# How to create a point cloud in Octave?

Tags: octave

I'm trying to run a MATLAB script to reconstruct a point cloud in Octave. Unfortunately the functions `ptCloud` and `pcwrite` are not implemented in Octave. Is there a way to replace them in Octave?

My code looks like this.

```
rad = data(:,1).*3.14./180; 
[x,y,z] = pol2cart(rad,data(:,2),data(:,3));  
M = [x,y,z];   
ptCloud = pointCloud(M);
pcwrite(ptCloud,'S4P1','PLYFormat','ascii');
```

Comment: in principle a point cloud is simply an Mx3 array. You could plot it by doing plot3(X,Y,Z) etc. To convert to ply format, you can import it into meshlab and export it in the format you want.

Comment: I believe Meshlab provides an api / commandline executable you could call from within octave if you want to be able to do your conversion programmatically (have a look at the meshlabserver executable)

Comment: Thanks, using plot3(x,y,z) helped me. I'm sorry to ask but how do I save my matrix to a format that Meshlab can read? I was trying to save it by doing `save -ascii ptCloud` but got an error for `wrong type argument 'scalar struct'`. Also I was trying to call Meshlab in Octave by means of the meshlabserver (e.g. [link](https://www.mankier.com/1/meshlabserver) and [link](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/blob/master/src/meshlabserver/meshlabserver.txt)) but was not really able to do so.

Comment: The .xyz format simply seems to be three 'space-delimited' columns of numbers. Presumably you can produce one easily via the `dlmwrite` command (e.g. `dlmwrite( 'outfile.xyz', X, ' ')` ). Having said that, the output of `save -ascii` also seemed to import fine in Meshlab (as long as you give it the appropriate `.xyz` extension)

Comment: Ah, the octave error you're referring to simply means that you were trying to save a struct as an ascii file, when this only works for numerical arrays, not structs.

Comment: I have successfully made a conversion from an .xyz file to an .ply one via the following command on the (linux) terminal: `meshlabserver -i myfile.xyz -o myfile.ply`. This assumes meshlab has been installed correctly and that the meshlabserver command is on your system path and accessible etc etc.  (Having said that, Meshlab can read .xyz files just fine, no need for conversion in the first place, if your objective is to simply load the mesh into meshlab)

Comment: Saving the matrix as a .xyz file worked. However, the conversion to a .ply file does not work for me yet. I think Meshlab is installed correctly, but to call it in Octave, don't I have to run the .exe first somehow? Unfortunately I'm not so familiar with it, but I thought about something like this: `C:\Program Files\VCG\MeshLab\meshlabserver.exe -i C:\Users\file location\outfile.xyz -o C:\Users\file location\outfile.ply`. Could this be realized in Octave or do maybe you have another solution?

Comment: you can call external (i.e. "system") commands from within octave using the `system` function. Alternatively (and perhaps more reasonably), you can create a bash script (or .bat script in windows) which runs your octave script first, and the meshlab conversion second.

Comment: Okay I created a .bat script with the following content `"C:\Program Files\VCG\MeshLab\meshlabserver.exe" -i C:\Users\marci\Desktop\Test\outfile.xyz -o C:\Users\marci\Desktop\Test\outfile.ply`and do `system("saveply.bat");`to call it in Octave and it works really fine. Thanks for your help.